# Get element from python list

Tags: python, string, mongodb, list

i'm new in python. I'm getting from mongodb the field 'url' and it's value from some records. So, I have this information in the variable called urls.

I do this,

```
for url in urls: # urls refers to the url's fetched from db
    print url
```

That print shows this

```
{u'url': u'/politica/2017/03/05/anibal-fernandez-nunca-tuve-vocacion-de-ser-candidato-a-gobernador/'}
```

I want to get this string

```
/politica/2017/03/05/anibal-fernandez-nunca-tuve-vocacion-de-ser-candidato-a-gobernador/
```

I tried differents ways but can't accomplish.

Comment: What different ways have you tried?

Comment: thats actually a dictionary, not a list. So you need to pull out the value associated with the `url` key like `url["url"]`

Comment: @Simon oh! Thank you. That's why when I tried to access like a list I got an  error in execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently mongodb gives you a list of dictionaries. So you can try the following code:

```
for url in urls:
    print url["url"]
```

You can also use a list comprehension to get all URLs in a list:

```
extracted_urls = [url["url"] for url in urls]
```

Comment: If I do it like this, I get this error. Cursor' object has no attribute 'values'. If I do it like this `url["url"]` I get the value

Comment: Oh, so you don't get a dictionary, but rather a list of dictionaries... I modified my answer to reflect that.